# How to configure DCEVM just to reload only modified class?

Tags: java, hotswap

I was using JRebel trial and switched to DCEVM after trial ended. The difference i observed is, JRebel just reloads the class that is modified whereas DCEVM is almost restarting my tomcat that takes good amount of time.

Is there any setting in DCEVM to just load modified class? I have installed DCEVM as Alternate JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HotswapAgent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/) is free alternative to JRebel. It is extension to DCEVM  that supports many Java frameworks and servlet containers. There is also documentation howto setup IDE to use DCEVM + HotswapAgent correctly.

Comment: Getting an error on server startup  -                                                                                                                                                                                                   Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: The specified procedure could not be found

Comment: Its my bad, the DCEVM version and my JDK were not same. After using right DCEVM, server started.